# create a uitextfield or any uilabel without any constraint auto layout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am working on the auto layout. However, there is a small problem about I can not figure it out. Google it but can not find the clue.

[image]

As we can see, the tutorial first created uitextfield1 without any constraints at all. However, when I am trying to drag and drop another uitextfield2 to the view, there is constraints associated with it 
My question is how to create an uitextfield with no constraint ( width + height )

Edited (for more details what I am trying to achieve)
[image]

For the picture above, we can see the textfield2 has the width constraint of 203. However, the textfield1 does not have width constraint like below
[image]

Comment: Uncheck autolayout option in your interface builder if you dont want autolayout..

Comment: please look at the my comment below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the components in the view has there own constrains, but Xcode only shows you the ones for the selected component. If you don't want the Autolayout constraints in a view or Storyboard then disable it in Xcode

Comment: if you take a look at the picture above, the tutorial still uses the auto layout for Example View Controller but its uitextfield1 does not have its own width, height constraint.

Comment: ok, I see, that's because the constraints of the text field are inside the view constraints, its position and size are set with respect the other components in the view

Comment: for example, if in an empty view you add a `UITextField` centered in the view and you set it to use the full size of the parent view (from blue line to blue line) you will see that its constrains "disappears"

Comment: I have just added more info for the OP, please take a look at it. I just tried but still getting the width constraint like [here](http://cl.ly/MaSx)

Comment: the width of the `textfield1` is defined by the position constrains (the distance to label in the left side and to the view border in the right side), thats why this component don't has a width constraints